# Cannot use indexing in view because of IEnumerable in Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, for-loop, foreach, ienumerable

In my Model I have IEnumerable, and due to this I cannot use for loop in view. If I use foreach the Html generated doesn't have indexing, which is what I need. How do I solve this problem.
I'm trying to use same view model to create and edit and I'm having problem in the edit part.

```
    public class CreateModule
    {
        //Empty form to handle form serialization
        public CreateModule()
        {
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }

        public string KindName { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        public string SelectedModuleTypeName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypeNames { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    }
    public class Property
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my view where I have used both for and foreach, but I have commented for as I cannot use indexing in it currently

```
  @*
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
  {
     <label class="label">@Model.Properties[i].Value</label>
     <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Properties[i].Value, new { @value = Model.Properties[i].Value })</div>
   }
  *@

   @foreach (var properties in Model.Properties)
   {
      <div class="label">@properties.Name</div>
      <div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => properties.Value, new { @value = properties.Value })</div>
      <br/>
    }
```

Currently Html.Textbox for generates following two names which doesn't have indexing in it
 **properties.value**
because of this the values that are submitted during the post are Null. If I use for loop then I think my properties.value will change to **properties[0].value** and **properties[1].value**??? I'm not sure, but that is what I'm trying to achieve.

If I change my model from

```
 public IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

then my following method in repository would not work as it reutrns IQueryable for value properties, and ***casting from IQueryable to List would not be possible.***

```
public CreateModule GetModuleDetails(long id)
{
     var module = (_dbSis.Modules.Where(t => t.Id == id).Select(m => new CreateModule
      {
         Id = id,
         ModuleId = m.ModuleId,
         TypeName = m.ModuleType.TypeName,
         KindName = m.ModuleType.ModuleKind.KindName,
         Properties = m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(
                    x => new Property { Name = x.Property.Name, Value = x.Value })
       }));

       return (module.FirstOrDefault());
  }
```

Comment: Where do you even need the index? Currently the difference of loops is irrelevant.

Comment: currently if I have two properties name and two properties value, my foreach loop is generating the names `properties.value` for both the textbox where properties value are shown. I want it to be shown not as `properties.value` but `properties[0].value` and `properties[1].value`, wouldn't this be achieved by using for loop?

Comment: If I'm interpreting you correctly, no, not at all.

Comment: then how would I be possible to achieve indexing to the html that is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view like below, name it Property.cshtml, and put it under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.

```
@model MyApp.Models.Property

<div class="label">@Model.Name</div>
<div class="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Value)</div>
<br/>
```

Then, replace the foreach loop in your View with this:

```
@EditorFor(model => model.Properties)
```